# How is most informative feature percentage is calculated in Naive Bayes nltk python?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, logistic-regression

We usually get the following results when we run the below command :-

```
 classifier.show_most_informative_features(10)
```

Results:

```
Most Informative Features
             outstanding = 1                 pos : neg    =     13.9 : 1.0
               insulting = 1                 neg : pos    =     13.7 : 1.0
              vulnerable = 1                 pos : neg    =     13.0 : 1.0
               ludicrous = 1                 neg : pos    =     12.6 : 1.0
             uninvolving = 1                 neg : pos    =     12.3 : 1.0
              astounding = 1                 pos : neg    =     11.7 : 1.0
```

Does anybody knows how this 13.9, 13.7 etc is calculated?

Also, We can get the most informative features with the following method classifier.show_most_informative_features(10) with Naive bayes but if we want to get the same results using logistic regression, please could somebody suggest the way to get that. I saw one post on stackoverflow but that requires vector which I am not using to create features.

```
classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set)
print("Original Naive bayes accuracy percent: ", nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier,dev_set)* 100)
classifier.show_most_informative_features(10)

LogisticRegression_classifier = SklearnClassifier(LogisticRegression())
LogisticRegression_classifier.train(train_set)
print("LogisticRegression  accuracy percent: ", nltk.classify.accuracy(LogisticRegression_classifier, dev_set)*100)
```

Answer (score 2):

The most informative features for [the Naive Bayes classifier in NLTK](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/classify/naivebayes.py#L147) is documented as such:

```
def most_informative_features(self, n=100):
    """
    Return a list of the 'most informative' features used by this
    classifier.  For the purpose of this function, the
    informativeness of a feature ``(fname,fval)`` is equal to the
    highest value of P(fname=fval|label), for any label, divided by
    the lowest value of P(fname=fval|label), for any label:
    |  max[ P(fname=fval|label1) / P(fname=fval|label2) ]
    """
    # The set of (fname, fval) pairs used by this classifier.
    features = set()
    # The max & min probability associated w/ each (fname, fval)
    # pair.  Maps (fname,fval) -> float.
    maxprob = defaultdict(lambda: 0.0)
    minprob = defaultdict(lambda: 1.0)

    for (label, fname), probdist in self._feature_probdist.items():
        for fval in probdist.samples():
            feature = (fname, fval)
            features.add(feature)
            p = probdist.prob(fval)
            maxprob[feature] = max(p, maxprob[feature])
            minprob[feature] = min(p, minprob[feature])
            if minprob[feature] == 0:
                features.discard(feature)

    # Convert features to a list, & sort it by how informative
    # features are.
    features = sorted(features,
                      key=lambda feature_:
                      minprob[feature_]/maxprob[feature_])
    return features[:n]
```

In the case of binary classification ('pos' vs 'neg'), where your features are from a unigram bag-of-word (BoW) models, the "information value" returned by the `most_informative_features()` function for the word `outstanding` is equals to:

```
 p('outstanding'|'pos') / p('outstanding'|'neg')
```

The function iterates through all features (in the case of unigram BoW models, features are words), and then take the top 100 words with the highest "information value".

---

The probability of a word given the tag is computed in the [`train()` function](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/classify/naivebayes.py#L182) using the Expected Likelihood Estimation from the [`ELEProbDist`](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/probability.py#L866) which is a [`LidstoneProbDist`](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/probability.py#L734) object under the hood where the `gamma` argument is set to 0.5, and it does:

```
class LidstoneProbDist(ProbDistI):
    """
    The Lidstone estimate for the probability distribution of the
    experiment used to generate a frequency distribution.  The
    "Lidstone estimate" is parameterized by a real number *gamma*,
    which typically ranges from 0 to 1.  The Lidstone estimate
    approximates the probability of a sample with count *c* from an
    experiment with *N* outcomes and *B* bins as
    ``c+gamma)/(N+B*gamma)``.  This is equivalent to adding
    *gamma* to the count for each bin, and taking the maximum
    likelihood estimate of the resulting frequency distribution.
    """
```

Comment: Thanks alvas! Do you know any code that will work for skilearn logistic regression as well which doesn't use vector? I wanted to understand what are the words that helps more in logistic regression to give better results